# firebase authUser block prevents ViewController from dismissing

Tags: uiviewcontroller, firebase, objective-c-blocks

I use this firebase block in a ViewController for user authentication:

```
[ref authUser:@"x@y.de" password:@"xyz" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, FAuthData *authData) {
if (error) {
    [self goOffline];
} else {
    [self handleFBUser: authData completion:completion];
}
}];
```

but if I dismiss the VC, the VC is hidden but still in memory (NSLog still shows messages every second in console).

UPDATE

After some more testing I found out that VC can be dismissed if the firebase login data was wrong and so

authData is nil

but if login data was correct and

authData is not nil

the VC can not be dismissed.

UPDATE2

Now I changed the code like this:

```
__weak FirebaseVC *weakSelf = self;
__weak void(^weakHandleResult)();

void(^handleResult)();

weakHandleResult = handleResult = ^(NSError *error, __weak FAuthData *firebaseUser) {
    if (error) {
        completion(error, Nil);
    } else {
        [weakSelf handleFBUser: firebaseUser completion:completion];
    }
};

[ref authUser:@"x@y.de" password:@"xyz" withCompletionBlock: handleResult];
```

But with the same result.

UPDATE3

Jay brought me to the right direction.

I call the authentication from another VC block, and there I have to set self also to "__weak weakself = self" and use weakself for the function in the block which calls the authentication in the other VC.

Comment: use ---    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             // do your stuff
           });

Comment: No, doesn't solve my problem, thank you for help

Comment: You may have a circular reference. We leverage viewControllers frequently and can dismiss and create them without an issue. Are you using ARC? Also, the first example is the way to do it - but what is 'completion' as it doesn't appear to be defined. If it's defined outside the block you need to define it accordingly as well.

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you very much! You brought me to the right direction.